# How to extract a type from a tagged union type in typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, union-types

Say there is already a type defined as this:

```
export type Item = {
  type: 'text',
  content: string
} | {
  type: 'link',
  url: string
}
```

Is it possible to extract the `link` part from the type `Item`? I mean, is it possible to define a type `ExtractTypeFrom`:

```
type LinkItem = ExtractType<Item, 'type', 'link'>
```

And the `LinkItem` will be:

```
{
  type: 'link',
  url: string
}
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Yes it is possible you are very close, you can use the predefined `Extract` conditional type. You can will need to pass in, as the second argument, a type that can be a base type for the type you are seeking:

```
type LinkItem = Extract<Item, { type: 'link' }> // will be  { type: "link"; url: string; }
```

Comment: awesome, thanks! if you want to have an "Extractor" type, you can define it like this: `type ItemExtractor<Match extends Partial<Item>> = Extract<Item, Match>`, then you can use it like this: `type LinkItem = ItemExtractor<{ type: 'link' }>` where the generic parameter `{ type: 'link' }` is typechecked to be actually a valid case for `Item`.

Comment: I love how close the OP's guess was to the real answer :-) Better than my attempt which was `Item & { type: 'link' }` (and does not work)

Comment: And a surprisingly straightforward definition, too :)
`type Extract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never;`