# Extract a union type in tagged union

Tags: typescript

I have a type in my code

```
   type Test = {
      selector:
        | "t1"
        | "t2"
        | "t3"; // and t4 t5 ...
      data: any;
    }
  | {
      selector: "temp";
      data: any;
      prev: any;
    };
```

So I'm wondering how to extract `t1` from this type?

I already see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52943170/1827594

this works well

```
type Data = Extract<Test , { selector: "t1" | "t2" | "t3" /* and t4 t5 */ }>
```

but this is not working

```
type Data = Extract<Test , { selector: "t1" }> // the type of Data is never
```

So if it's more than two union type ( t3, t4 and ... ) , I have to repeat all these key.

Is there any way to extract `t1` from `Test` without providing `t2,t3,...`?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=5&pln=15&pc=1#code/AQFwngDgpsAqUGcTALzAN4Chg9wqANlAMYgD2ATgFza50A%20wARCAIxO106MsBMHXXDxABmJgG5gAeinAAhgDsAJqAAsoAKzAAdLs64lckHKryFYcfoC%20tRlkH4ipSqZZQAthAn6ch46cULH2AICigANwDzS2ArS0xwaGAAESM5VGAAUQAPEAo5UgAeeCRgABoMYEcScmpmNiZgYX4m%20rFpACozFRB1EC0O2SsAPgTIGFTjXgycvIKQYsRkCvQqwhqXevZY4aA)

**UPDATE**

The `Test` type is simplify for asking question, I'm looking for **dynamic** way to achieve this and not related to other field in `Test` ( because the type change frequently )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using TS3.9+, which [aggressively reduces intersections of types with conflicting discriminant properties to `never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#intersections-reduced-by-discriminant-properties), you can write what you're doing this way:

```
// TS 3.9+
type ExtractOverlaps<T, U> = T extends any ? (U & T extends never ? never : T) : never;

type Data = ExtractOverlaps<Test, { selector: "t1" }>;
/* type Data = {
    selector: "t1" | "t2" | "t3";
    data: any;
} */
```

Here we are splitting `T` up into its union members, and for each one, seeing if it reduces to `never` when intersected with `U`.  If so, then we don't want that union member.  If not, then we do want it.  This produces the `Data` you want.

---

If you're still using TS3.8 and below, then we could synthesize the operation of reducing intersections of incompatible objects to `never`, but it's clunky and I don't want to go into all the possible edge cases:

```
// works in TS3.8-
type ReduceNeverPropsToNever<T> =
  { [K in keyof T]-?: [T[K]] extends [never] ? unknown : never }[keyof T] extends
  never ? T : never;

type ExtractOverlaps<T, U> = T extends any ? (
  ReduceNeverPropsToNever<U & T> extends never ? never : T
) : never;

type Data = ExtractOverlaps<Test, { selector: "t1" }>;
/* type Data = {
    selector: "t1" | "t2" | "t3";
    data: any;
} */
```

---

Of course, nothing says you need to replace `Extract<T, U>` with something else of the same shape.  If you're okay specifying the discriminant property name and value separately, you can do it this way:

```
type ExtractCompatible<T, K extends keyof T, V extends T[K]> =
  T extends any ? [V] extends [T[K]] ? T : never : never;

type Data = ExtractCompatible<Test, "selector", "t1">;  
/* type Data = {
  selector: "t1" | "t2" | "t3";
  data: any;
} */
```

Here we are splitting `T` into its union members, and for each one, checking if `V` is assignable to `T[K]`.  We're explicitly naming the property `K` and the value `V` to look for, so we don't have to do intersections or other weird juggling.  This is probably the solution I'd suggest unless you need a drop-in replacement for `Extract`.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-mCw61CbTGDtAPmkMjEPbah7N2HSPg86Xa6xu4bR7Jl5veFfOy-FgAoHUUFtqCQq6oGFwwe2H6MUe8NG8TFubA44I+MKE4kk0kxeBxBJQACCeDmZCiwFl5VpUeyNzjwAAwiRnDpZQAjAj1E0MrVpm3rqrATQAGqmnM5qGlKmqim4YYgf03irBKkH+hm-QGkaNqdM2Gzhi2GB0tGM6drcxCft+97-hAzyIE09DWEOZD0Cxfzjtgk70tOHZzm4bFLkiq6ov8G6uNily7viB5kSSQA)

Comment: I accept this because, It's best dynamic way. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can write a custom extract function and use [the infer keyword](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ijK-1R-LFII) :

```
 type Test = {
      selector:
        | "t1"
        | "t2"
        | "t3"; // and t4 t5 ...
      data: number;
    }
  | {
      selector: "temp";
      data: any;
      prev: any;
 };

type TestExtract<T> = T extends { selector: "t1" | "t2" | "t3", data: infer U }
  ? { selector: "t1", data: U }
  : never; 

type Data = TestExtract<Test> // {selector: "t1" , data: number };
```

Comment: I want to create more than one Type, it's not only for `t1` for each of them I have a function and I want to exclude them in args, Im looking for answer to avoid writing `"t1"|"t2"|"t3"` everytime, your answer is what only for "t1", Is there any way to improve it?

Comment: Also for simplify my question, I only add `data` but there is more that just one field, as I see everytime I change `Test` type I need to change `TestExtract` Type, I'm just looking for more `dynamic` way

Comment: You can improve this by adding a second generic:
`type TestExtract<T, S> = T extends { selector: "t1" | "t2" | "t3", data: infer U }
  ? { selector: S, data: U }
  : never; ` then you can choose which selector you want `TestExtract<Test, 't1'>`

Answer (score 1):

**If `Test` union contains only these two well-defined members**

If the `Test` union will ever contain just the members described in the original post, the simplest solution is to solve the reversed problem. Instead of *extracting* the first member of the union, *exclude* the second member from the union.

```
type Data = Exclude<Test, { selector: "temp" }>
```

**If `Test` union contains any number of members**

This solution is more complicated but will work for bigger unions as well.

```
interface Selectable {
  selector: string;
}

type Extractor<T extends Selectable, U extends Selectable> =
  // For each member of the union T...
  T extends any
    // See if the member overlaps with U.
    ? U extends Pick<T, 'selector'>
      // If it does, return that member of the union.
      ? T
      // If not, return never.
      : never
    : never;

type Data = Extractor<Test, { selector: 't1' }>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=31&pc=49#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4BQUoB8oG90YPggBsIBjYAewCcAuKAcmAEYGtHgAmN7JgZgYBuKAHoRUAIYA7ACZRgAFnkBWKADoN%20AlBkTgE%20tJCCtUAL75sebRiKkKNekwgBbMENMZd%20w1OOeoMGoIADdff20LDCsAu3IqOkZ4ShcIHkZKYAALCGp0hjiHPJNIk1QASylgXIAzCTJoAGUSeIkAI1JcfEKE%20kRqSoBzEwtUUEgoAFEAD2BqeoSAHhgoCFmIWXgoZvt9DogAGigAVVX1ze2WinbSAD4UfDEoADEaVfqsqFSXNtyoShq8hyUAArlJypQpLANGp8Cs1tULkZTAB%20UTiZrQcqA7LQb6-aj-EK5YgSMBbADu5WyJ1hNhOZ0RMi2AAVymQANbLI4FK4JBi3AJop4ASUB1J0lAQR2CwBB1Ch2T0X1cBP%20OOBYIhUjp9NgAXoosBUkyMogcoVUCkoVyuvp1uJ1FM9AduTK42gABE9BIUFNZvMissEMAjjgoD1HBxWOZboIgA)

---

Note the use of `T extends any`. It looks awkward — after all, every type extends `any`, so this condition is always met. However, using conditional types allows you to iterate over each member of the union which is what we want. Read more on [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).

Comment: That will still give him the same result as `type Data = Extract<Test , { selector: "t1" | "t2" | "t3" }>`

Comment: the other selector is not one. there is more than these two

Comment: your answer might be better than the one I'm suggesting then. Good job 

Comment: I updated my answer. It should work with unions of any size.